# Why does ZoneInfo("UTC") do different time conversions from timezone.utc?

Tags: python, datetime, zoneinfo

I was trying to convert a datetime from one timezone to another. I'm in the process of updating our Python codebase to stop relying on utilities we don't need anymore. In particular, I'm deprecating our use of `arrow` and `pytz`. In doing so, I noticed some strange behavior from `ZoneInfo("UTC")`.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
# This gives datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC'))

# Let's say I try to convert it to America/Toronto timezone
jan1_in_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/Toronto"))

# This gives me the SAME date time ?!?!?
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Toronto'))


# However, if I use timezone.utc instead
jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

# This works as expected
jan1_in_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/Toronto"))

# this correctly calculates a -5 offset
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Toronto'))
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. "UTC" is in the list of `zoneinfo.available_timezones()`. Using "utc" raises an error.

I also noticed this oddity. Calculating the `utcoffset` from the `ZoneInfo("UTC")` isn't `0`.

```py
jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
ZoneInfo("UTC").utcoffset(jan1_in_utc)
```

Where as if I use `timezone.utc`, there's no time difference.

```py
jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

timezone.utc.utcoffset(jan1_in_utc)
# This gives datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Now I'm unsure if I should use `ZoneInfo` at all, or if I should still rely on `pytz` and `arrow`. Any thoughts? Clearly, I'm missing something!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why, but I've narrowed the scope of the issue. When we're building our Docker containers, we added a line to set `/etc/timezone` to be `America/Toronto`. That causes `ZoneInfo.utcoffset` to behave differently.

Because of this, the `utcoffset` method appears to pick up that timezone and calculate offsets differently.

```py
>>> jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
>>> ZoneInfo("UTC").utcoffset(jan1_in_utc)
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)
```

It returns 1 day minus 19 hours which is -5 hours. That's the offset for America/Toronto. I believe this explains why no adjustment is made to the time. `ZoneInfo` seems to think I'm converting from America/Toronto to America/Toronto, so no change is made to the `datetime`.

Python's `datetime.timezone.utc` doesn't exhibit this behavior. Even with `/etc/timezone` set to `America/Toronto` it calculates the offset correctly.

```py
>>> jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
>>> ZoneInfo("UTC").utcoffset(jan1_in_utc)
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. Did you make sure [tzdata](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/) is installed and up-to-date?

On

```
Python 3.9.15 (main, Oct 30 2022, 10:17:28) 
[GCC 11.3.0] on linux
```

I get Toronto time at UTC-5 as expected for both options:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
jan1_in_utc = jan1_in_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/Toronto"))
print(repr(jan1_in_utc))
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Toronto'))

jan1_in_utc = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-01T08:00').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
jan1_in_utc = jan1_in_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/Toronto"))
print(repr(jan1_in_utc))
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Toronto'))
```